# Best type of project for automation and why?

Tags: c#, automation

I was just wondering what the the best type of C# project would be in order to allow automation. It will most likely be sat on a server and will need to be capable of being run once every two hours. The app will communicate with a database in order to refresh some tables from one server to another.

What would be your preference for this? A winforms app or a console app and for what reasons?

#### Update:

I should add that management has stated that they would prefer it not to be a web service as that would have been my first choice too.

Comment: If the app is going to reside in a separate server it can be implemented as a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Probably best going for a Windows Service if you want it to be automatically fired every 2 hours.  Otherwise, if a real person is going to log in and load it up then it doesn't really matter if it's a Win Forms or a Console App.  Just as long as the functionality is there :)

Comment: The app will most likely reside on the server to be refreshed and communicate to the other server from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

A console app or winforms app would have to be launched by a logged in user. A Windows Service will run in the background independent of the current user.

For development, I mostly start with a console app because it's easier to deploy and test and then turn in into a windows service and deploy it.

Comment: @CSharpened - Note you can write a Windows Service that also can be ran as a Console App. The SQL Server service is implemented like this for example. The notable difference between running as a Service vs as a Console App is the security environment.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry I misunderstood and read windows service to be web service. It is a bit early in the morning. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Console application for sure.
Winforms is good when there's a need for user input, but as far as I understand, there will be no user input involved here.

You can set the Windows Scheduler to run your Console application every X hours, and it will run and complete without any further interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You need task scheduler that will spawn every configurable time and do the job for you. You can also have windows service which can do this as well. But Task scheduler would be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

A service application is probably your best solution, since it can be run without anyone having to be logged into a session on the server. From within the Service application, just use a Timer or equivalent to run your processes every few hours.

Otherwise, you can write a script (VBScript, Powershell, CMD, etc.) that does the work, then use Windows Task Scheduler to run the process every two hours.